# Removing inline onclick event tracking code and putting it in an external file

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have many tracking codes attached to link tags (`onclick=""`) and these are scattered throughout my page and it looks very messy.

It looks like,

```
<a href="tel:+123456789" onclick="gtag('event', 'click', { 'event_category': 'Phone', 'event_label': 'Header phone link' });">+123456789</a>
```

I was wondering if they could all be removed and moved to an external js file to keep the page clean and readable. If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Consider:

**index.html**

```
<a href="tel:+123456789" id="header-phone">+123456789</a>
```

**app.js**

```
document.getElementById("header-phone").addEventListener("click", function() {
  gtag('event', 'click', { 'event_category': 'Phone', 'event_label': 'Header phone link' });
});
```

and then, at the bottom of the *index.html*, link the *app.js* using `<script>`

Comment: Thanks @wscourge, is this jquery the same? `jQuery("#header-phone").click(function() {
  gtag('event', 'click', { 'event_category': 'Phone', 'event_label': 'Header phone link' });
});`

Comment: Yes, it is. Happy to be helpfull :)